# Capistrano Migrations Deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I have a question about Ruby on Rails and Capistrano deploys. The first thing I do is deploy my Rails App using:

```
cap deploy:update
```

When I have migration, I try to run the Capistrano command:

```
cap deploy:migrations
```

I get the error:

```
Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources
```

I have to SSH into the current folder of the server and manually run

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate
```

Which is obviously a huge pain to run every deploy with a migration.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: How did you end up solving this? Got the same problem. Tried  Ian solution and running the same commands from shh they work. But that did not solve the mystery

Answer (score 1):

You might need to uncomment and adjust the following lines in your `config/deploy.rb`:

```
# default_environment['PATH']='<your paths>:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
# default_environment['GEM_PATH']='<your paths>:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
```

Additionally, if you are using RVM, you might need to add a few lines:

```
# adjust if you are using RVM, remove if you are not
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2'
set :rvm_type, :user
```

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like the deploy:migrations task isn't getting the right bash environment. Can you see the full command that's being run on the server? Is it using sudo? Is it using bundler? Get the whole command and try running *that* from your SSH session.

Answer (score 0):

you have a newer version of **rake** gem on local, but the remote server has the older one which works correctly with Rails version you use.

Can you check it with "gem list |grep rake" local and remotely. you can specify **rake** gem version in your Gemfile and redeploy the application

```
#Gemfile
gem 'rake',  '0.8.7' # or '0.9.2'
```

Comment: I tried this. On my local machine the output is rake (10.0.3, 10.0.2, 10.0.0, 0.9.2.2)
On my production it is says
rake (10.0.3, 10.0.2)
BUT rake is show in red. Thats not a good sign is it? I already wrote in the gemfile to use 10.0.3

Comment: @Jepzen rake 0.8.7/0.9.2 is appropriate to Rails 2.3.*

Comment: Well my error is the same as original question but with different versions. So I thought this could help me as well.

Answer (score 0):

To pull in the Bundler Cap task, just add this to your **deploy.rb** file:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
```

Running cap deploy will now automatically run bundle install on the remote server with deployment-friendly options, and rake will be available for the following steps of the deployment.

A list of options that can be changed is available in the help for the cap task. To see it, run cap -e bundle:install.